# Бессмертный Service

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что мне нужно реализовать проект, типа чата.

Решили использовать библиотеку [Socket.IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io). Пока `FCM` не рассматриваем.

Чтобы в фоновом режиме получать сообщения использую `Service`. Вот:

```
public class SocketServiceProvider extends Service {

    private Socket mSocket;

    private final String EVENT_NEW_MESSAGE = "new_message";
    private final String LOG_TAG = "SocketServiceProvider";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "created()");
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
        if (mSocket == null)
            mSocket = BaseApplication.getSocket();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStartedCommand()");

        startSocket();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startSocket() {
        if (mSocket.connected()){
            stopSocket();
        }

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        mSocket.on(EVENT_NEW_MESSAGE, onNewMessage);

        mSocket.connect();
    }

    private void stopSocket() {
        mSocket.off();
        mSocket.disconnect();
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
                if (mSocket.connected()) {
                    isOnline = true;
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Подключено!");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = args -> {
        final JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
        final String username;
        final String message;
        try {
            username = data.getString("from");
            message = data.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, username + " написал: " + message);
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy()");

        stopSocket();

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, SocketServiceProvider.class));
    }
}
```

Только проблема в том, что когда телефон уходит в спящий режим, сообщения не приходят.

Попытался разбудить с `AlarmManager` в `onTaskRemoved()`, `onDestroy()`, безуспешно.

Еще при `onDestroy()` попробовал вызвать `BroadcastReceiver`, чтобы он запустил обратно мой `Service`, только не понял почему, но его метод `onReceive` не срабатывает.

Вот мой последний вариант, код который выложил. Там я уже использую не `startService`, а `startForegroundService`. И этот вариант сработал, по крайней мере не умирает. Только в этом случае, батарейку жестко кушает.

Пишут, что с помощью `JobIntentService` можно реализовать, но нигде не описано подробно.

Вопрос: Как же это сделать и как вы реализовывали такого рода задачи? И как с `JobIntentService` можно добиться этого?

Comment: Возможно, что ваш сервис глушит [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

Comment: чем WebSocket API не угодил?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, так и есть

Comment: @Tsyklop, считаете, если его использовать, то сервис не перейдет в спящий режим?

Comment: @DevOma зачем вообще спящий режим?

Comment: @Tsyklop, не совсем понял вас. Я говорю что из за Doze режим, мой сервис перестает работать и не перезапускается и соккет мой тоже перестает получать ивенты

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии N ForegroundService Единственный надежный метод оставаться всегда в работе. Соответственно, думаю вам надо всетаки внедрять push, т.е. в 
foreground вы держите socket, потом засыпаете и делаете полл не чаще чем раз в 15 минут, либо по получению пуша, а на стороне сервера отслеживаете если пользователь не поллит, то шлете пуш. Самое печальное что Google менял чень много раз бэкграунд на разных версиях и чтобы поддерживать все сценарии начиная с 4.0 ( с сервисом и фореграунд и т.д.) нужно делать много разных вариантов.

Comment: Да, я использую на данный момент ForegroundService и нормально, не умирает сервис, только вот аккумулятор кушает много